# Swift Codable: Include enum Coding Keys if API may add more properties to response JSON in the future

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, codable

I am using `Codable` to parse my `JSON` response object.

Is it a good idea to include `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey` so in the future if the `JSON` response object has extra properties added to it, they will be ignored and not cause a crash?

It's just a lot of extra code to backfill when you have 30 different models in the app.

Not sure if there is a way better way to handle this?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, if a json key is not part of your struct it will not be decoded.

Comment: If it has extra keys that doesn't line match, I believe it crashes.

Comment: @user1107173 That is not correct. They'll just be ignored. If you're seeing a crash due to unexpected JSON keys, please post your example JSON and struct and we can help you work through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example that runs fine and proves that extra json keys that are not defined in the struct will be ignored

```
let data = """
 { "id": 32, "name" : "abc", "other": "gbdfb"}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct JSONData: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}


do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(JSONData.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `No`.The `Codable` only decodes the values that are found in the `json`. Moreover, it isn't necessary if you add `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey` to every `Codable` Protocol. You may leave this with null value.

We use to write `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey` if the key isn't snakeCased. But Codable has it's own `keyDecodingStrategy`

```
let jsonString = """
[
    {
        "profile_name": "Ankur Lahiry",
    },
    {
        "profile_name": "Karim Rahman",
    }
]
"""

let jsonData = Data(jsonString.utf8)


struct Name : Codable {
    var profileName: String?
}


let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase // will solve enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey issue 
do {
    let names = try decoder.decode([Name].self, from: jsonData)
    print(names)
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```